# Solution to $y'(x) + \frac{1}{2}y(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x -1) y^3(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$y'(x)+\frac12y(x)=\frac12(x-1)y^3(x)$$

I realize it's a Bernoulli diff. equation so i used the substitution: $z = \frac{1}{y^2}$

and I come up with the equation: $-zz' + z = x -1$ , which I have tried to solve using the variation of parameters method and my homogenous solution to $-zz' + z= 0$ is $z=x + C$ with $C$ a constant. I do not know which function to use for the variation of parameters method as I have tried using $z= (x + C)u(x)$ and the whole thing becomes a mess, I want help on what step to take if I am to use the method of variation of parameters given my progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$-zz' + z = x -1$$
You have an extra $z$. It should be: $$-z' + z = x -1$$
Then use $\mu( x)=e^{-x}$ as an integrating factor:
$$(ze^{-x})'=(1-x)e^{-x}$$
Integrate.

Comment: Oh my bad, thanks for pointing out that, I had made a mistake of differentiating $\frac{1}{y^2}$ in the first place

Comment: Yes you made a little mistake. Now integrate and you will find the solution. @Fnechz +1 for your attempts

Comment: From here I can proceed, let me integrate

Comment: Ok no problem @Fnechz